# Strange behavior on webview 3 plugin with Ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, typescript, webview, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have a huge issue with `Webview 3`. One of our dev upgraded it to `webview 3` without using [Ionic native webview plugi](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/ionic-webview/)n and it is working fine at the moment on `Ionic 3` app. [According to the doc](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#plugin-requirements) it has breaking change like so

`Replace any usages of window.Ionic.normalizeURL() with window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc()`

But that dev didn't do that too. But `camera` functionality is also working fine. i.e.

`imageURI = normalizeURL(imageURI)` is working fine on `webview 3`. Can you tell me what was this behavior? What kind of issues will this app have in the future?

This is his files:

*package.json*

```
{
    "name": "amr",
    "version": "3.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "config": {
        "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "ios-deploy": "^1.9.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
        "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.18.0",
        "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^4.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/branch-io": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^4.9.1",
        "@ionic-native/contacts": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^4.14.0",
        "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.12.2",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.14.0",
        "@ionic-native/image-resizer": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.12.0",
        "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/market": "^4.18.0",
        "@ionic-native/mixpanel": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/music-controls": "^4.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/sms": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.9.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic/pro": "^1.0.20",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
        "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
        "@vimeo/player": "^2.6.3",
        "angular-progress-bar": "^1.0.3",
        "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^2.0.0",
        "angular2-google-place": "^2.0.2",
        "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
        "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
        "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
        "branch-cordova-sdk": "^3.1.5",
        "com.synconset.imagepicker": "^2.1.10",
        "cordova-android": "6.4.0",
        "cordova-clipboard": "^1.2.1",
        "cordova-custom-config": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
        "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
        "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "git+https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-contacts": "^3.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^0.9.10",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^2.5.0",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.4.6",
        "cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git#2.6.0",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-market": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": "^2.3.6",
        "cordova-plugin-mixpanel": "^4.5.2",
        "cordova-plugin-music-controls": "^2.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.4",
        "cordova-sms-plugin": "^0.1.13",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.6.0",
        "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.10",
        "css-animator": "^2.3.0",
        "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
        "firebase": "4.8.2",
        "google-maps": "^3.2.1",
        "info.protonet.imageresizer": "^0.1.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionic2-auto-complete": "^1.6.2-alpha",
        "ionic2-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.0.2",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "list": "1.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.23.0",
        "ng-lazyload-image": "3.4.2",
        "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
        "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.4.6",
        "promise-polyfill": "^8.0.0",
        "pubnub": "^4.21.5",
        "pubnub-angular2": "^1.3.1",
        "raven-js": "^3.27.0",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "tslib": "^1.9.3",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.1",
        "@ionic/lab": "1.0.11",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.16",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {
                "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Upload profile pic",
                "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Upload profile pic",
                "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the library."
            },
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
                "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate your Location"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-contacts": {
                "CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To invite Friends"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "info.protonet.imageresizer": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
            "cordova-plugin-music-controls": {},
            "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
            "cordova-clipboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "com.synconset.imagepicker": {
                "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the library.",
                "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the library."
            },
            "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
                "APP_ID": "22",
                "APP_NAME": "You Are a CEO",
                "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-mixpanel": {
                "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
                "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "rp0",
                "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "rp0",
                "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.0.1",
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+",
                "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location while this app runs only.",
                "LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location always, even this app runs in background."
            },
            "branch-cordova-sdk": {},
            "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": {
                "GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11+",
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION": "23+",
                "ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
                "SMALL_ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
                "ACCOUNT_NAME": "@string/app_name",
                "ACCOUNT_LABEL": "@string/app_name",
                "ACCOUNT_TYPE": "$PACKAGE_NAME.account",
                "CONTENT_AUTHORITY": "$PACKAGE_NAME",
                "ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app always requires location tracking"
            },
            "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
            "cordova-sms-plugin": {},
            "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
                "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
            },
            "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
            "cordova-custom-config": {},
            "cordova-plugin-market": {}
        },
        "cordova-plugin-ionic": {
            "APP_ID": "2",
            "CHANNEL_NAME": "Production",
            "UPDATE_METHOD": "background",
            "MAX_STORE": "2"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
        "platforms": [
            "ios",
            "android"
        ]
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android",
        "ios"
    ]
}
```

*config.xml*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="mobile" version="4.5.32" versionCode="4.5.32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>You</name>
    <description>of you.</description>
    <author email="ww.com" href="http://w.com/">You</author>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="30000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="sdcard,cache" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>You can upload your profile picture using your Photo Library</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>You can upload your profile picture using your camera</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSContactsUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>To invite Friends </string>
        </config-file>
        <preference default="This app needs contact access" name="CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <custom-config-file parent="UIStatusBarHidden" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <true />
        </custom-config-file>
        <custom-config-file parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <false />
        </custom-config-file>
    </platform>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSContactsUsageDescription">
        <string>need contacts access to search friends</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
        <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
        <string>need photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription">
        <string>need photo library access to save pictures there</string>
    </edit-config>
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-music-controls" spec="^2.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="^3.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="^2.0.19" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="^0.1.9" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="com.synconset.imagepicker" spec="^2.1.10">
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the library." />
        <variable name="PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the library." />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^2.5.0">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="22" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="You Are a CEO" />
        <variable name="FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION" value="4.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.4.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mixpanel" spec="^4.5.0">
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-document-viewer" spec="^0.9.10" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.4.6">
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="rp0" />
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="p0" />
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="15.0.1" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <branch-config>
        <branch-key value="32" />
        <uri-scheme value="youareaceo" />
        <link-domain value="lsa3.app.link" />
        <android-testmode value="false" />
        <ios-team-release value="2ZTVGV2634" />
    </branch-config>
    <plugin name="branch-cordova-sdk" spec="^3.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="^2.3.6">
        <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11+" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" value="23+" />
        <variable name="ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
        <variable name="SMALL_ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_NAME" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" value="$PACKAGE_NAME.account" />
        <variable name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" value="$PACKAGE_NAME" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^4.0.10" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sms-plugin" spec="^0.1.13" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-clipboard" spec="^1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="git+https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Upload profile pic" />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Upload profile pic" />
        <variable name="PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the library." />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To locate your Location" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="^3.0.1">
        <variable name="CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To invite Friends" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="^2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="info.protonet.imageresizer" spec="^0.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder" spec="^3.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-market" spec="1.2.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5" />
    <engine name="android" spec="6.4.0" />
</widget>
```

But when I followed [this doc](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/ionic-webview/) with `ionic 3` app it shows [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250754/webview-3-upgrade-with-ionic-native-5-and-ionic-3-app) on the device. Can I have any explanation for this behavior?

**Git repo:** https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/webview-3-with-ionic-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`normalizeURL` calls `convertFileSrc` internally and shows a warning telling you it's deprecated. It will probably go away on next major release, so you are safe for now, but might not on next release.

Comment: Is that meaning we cannot use `webview 3+` with `Ionic 3` app due to the heavy dependency of `native 5+`?

Comment: I mean in next major release of webview plugin (4.x) might remove the normalizeURL function. You can safely use version 3 with ionic 3. And even if the version 4.x of the webview removes the normalizeURL, you still can use convertFileSrc instead, it does the same thing, it just changed the name.

Comment: But here you can see that `Ionic native 5+` require `Angular 7+`. But `Ionic 3` only works with `Angular 5+`. Then how `Ionic 3` and `Ionic native 5+` works together? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/releases/tag/v5.0.0-beta.22

Comment: Here you can see that we need `native 5+` with `webview 3+`https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/ionic-webview

Comment: Please see the issue here on git with `Ionic 3` project: https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/webview-3-with-ionic-3

Comment: But no issue with `Ionic 4` and `webview 3+`. You can see that on this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250754/webview-3-upgrade-with-ionic-native-5-and-ionic-3-app

Comment: So, your problem has nothing to do with the webview plugin, but with ionic native 5. If you can’t use ionic native 5 you can still use convertFileSrc like this private win: any = window;
this.win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc();

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the answer which I expected. Nice to see an `Ionic Team Member` here on Stackoverflow where it is a very rare seen :)